# C# Entity Framework - why querying is much faster when an anonymous type is used rather than a class object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET Core project with SQL as database. My question is why does this code (using an anonymous type):

```
var libraries = await _repo.GetAllDynamicAsync<Library>(
    column: c => new { c.Application, c.CreatedBy, c.CreatedDate, c.Description, c.Id, c.ModifiedBy, c.ModifiedDate, c.Name, c.NormalizeName, c.RowVersion, c.isDeleted });
```

query much faster than this code (using a class instance):

```
var libraries = await _repo.GetAllDynamicAsync<Library>(
    column: c => c );
```

Both snippets of code return the same data.

Other code:

```
public class Library : ExtendedEntity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DocumentGroup> DocumentGroup { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
}

private IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    int? skip = null, int? take = null, bool asNoTracking = false,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null)
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        
    if (filter != null)
        query = query.Where(filter);

    if (include != null)
        query = include(query);

    if (orderBy != null)
        query = orderBy(query);

    if (skip.HasValue)
        query = query.Skip(skip.Value);

    if (take.HasValue)
        query = query.Take(take.Value);

    if (asNoTracking)
        query = query.AsNoTracking();

    return query;
}

public virtual async Task<DbEntity> GetAllDynamicAsync<TEntity>(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    int? skip = null, int? take = null, bool asNoTracking = false,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> column = null)
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    DbEntity dbEntity = new DbEntity();
    dbEntity.Count = await GetQueryable<TEntity>(filter, orderBy, null, null, asNoTracking, include).Select(column).CountAsync();
    dbEntity.Data = await GetQueryable<TEntity>(filter, orderBy, skip, take, asNoTracking, include).Select(column).ToListAsync();
    return dbEntity;
}
```

Can someone please explain this? Why is the code using an anonymous type faster than the code using the an object itself?

Also kindly note that I'm new to Entity Framework. So if you think I'm doing it wrong or there's a better way to do querying, please kindly let me know. Thank you!

Comment: The faster one is probably return less data (less columns).

Comment: hi, thank you for replying. Base on my testing, it returns same columns. As I explicitly type all the properties of Library in the first snippet. I'm also using debugging in visual studio, and can confirm they both returned the same columns.

Comment: View the generated queries : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework

Comment: i didn't know about this one. i will definitely try this! will give feedback later on. thank you!

Comment: Repositories like that should not exist

Comment: With class object entities are tracked by default. I think that's the reason.

Comment: @AluanHaddad may I know why, sir? What is your suggestion?

Comment: Because LINQ queries are more readable and composable than passing a half a dozen parameters.